# OkHttp binding library for Xamarin Android throwing error

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin

I'm attempting to use the [OkHttp-Xamarin](https://github.com/paulcbetts/OkHttp-Xamarin) library in a Xamarin Android application. Whenever I try to create a new OkHttpNetworkHandler I get the exception below.

Line:

`var handler = new OkHttpNetworkHandler();`

Throws:

```
[] Missing method Android.Runtime.JNIEnv::AllocObject(Type) in assembly Mono.Android.dll, referenced in assembly /data/data/com.my.app/files/.__override__/OkHttp.dll
[MonoDroid] UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.AllocObject'.
[MonoDroid] at ModernHttpClient.OkHttpNetworkHandler..ctor () <IL 0x00001, 0x00057>
```

I am using prebuilt binaries from [ModernHttpClient](https://github.com/paulcbetts/ModernHttpClient/releases) version 0.9. My minimum Android version is set to 2.3 and target is set to 4.2. I'm using Xamarin Studio 4.0.13 and Mono 3.2.3.

Comment: Having exactly the same issue right now, cannot resolve it :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really an answer to why the Exception is being thrown but at the suggestion of Paul Betts I switched to the Alpha channel and things are working now.

Comment: I bet if you rebuilt his libraries from source, you could get it to work on stable. A lot of times Xamarin breaks compatibility between versions (at least for Android), unless you rebuild.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks heaps for these posts. After 'more than I care to admit' hours I've got ModernHttpClient working... having to learn about Make and Maven along the way. There's no better way to learn a system by 'diving in and finding the bugs' is there! This thread provided much needed signposts.

Answer (score 2):

So this looks like the first call to your binding code.

A couple things could be going on here:

- Make sure you are using `EmbeddedJar` instead of `InputJar` as the build action for the jar file. Otherwise, you have to include the jar with your main Android application.
- Make sure your main application has a reference to the binding DLL, it causes problems if only a dependent project has the reference.

If neither of those fix your issue, let me know, I think there is a working binding Paul Betts has for this library.

Comment: I am using Paul Betts binding library, as stated above I'm using his 0.9 release of ModernHttpClient. I set up a test project in case there was something wrong with the project I was working on: https://github.com/jdehlin/OkHttpTest. Bare bones, single project solution, and I am still getting the exception. In addition to the information above, I'm running Xamarin Studio (indie) on OSX.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I'm having the same problem. I noticed your project has  `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>`, and Paul is using 2.3. I tried changing it, but then your app wouldn't deploy anymore. Is your app using Android 4.x features?

Comment: That test app shouldn't be using any advanced features so not sure why it won't deploy. I don't believe the actual project I'm working on is using anything from 4.x either. When I get home I'll try messing around with the target version. Thanks.

Comment: Messed around with the TargetFrameworkVersion and got it to deploy (by turning off fast deployment). Still getting the same error though. Also tried using the latest release of ModernHttpClient dlls (1.0.0) with no difference.